# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of Undefined (reading 'getTotalLength')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gsap

I'm trying to animate the SVG with GSAP. But the console.log says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get total length')". It reacts project and this is the code I used inside of "**useEffect"**.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
    useEffect(() => {

        for(let i = 1; null != existElementId("circle" + i); i++){

            let tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1 });

        tl.to("#dot" + i, {
        duration: document.querySelectorAll("#curve" + i + "path")[0].getTotalLength() / 200,
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatDelay: 0,
        yoyo: false,
        ease: "none",
        motionPath: {
            path: "#curve" + i + "path",
            align: "#curve" + i + "path",
            
            alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
        }
        });
        
    
        tl.pause()
    existElementId("circle" + i).onmouseover = () => {
        tl.play()
    }
    existElementId("circle" + i).onmouseleave = () => {
        tl.pause().time(0)
    }
    
    }
    
    }, []);
```

I try to search on google but most of the answers were about "null"

This is the original code in Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-svg----3333-copy-copy-8olgrp?file=/src/components/MainSVG.js

Comment: null/undefined... they are basically the same thing when trying to access properties. The issue is that `document.querySelectorAll("#curve" + i + "path")[0]` is undefined. Use a null-check/guard-clause when accessing into potentially null/undefined values. Also, try to use React refs instead of querying the DOM, DOM queries are considered anti-pattern. If you [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve] we might be able to better say why some DOMNode is unavailable.

Comment: @DrewReese How can I use "useRef" hooks in there? Here I added the whole code in the sandbox. Can you check that?

Actually, this is what I want to do in my react: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-svg-html-esf3dc

Comment: You'd use the `useRef` hook to hold an array of created refs that are attached to each SVG group (`<g>`) tag.

Comment: Well, I'm still learning and I didn't get what you said. Maybe soon someday I'll be able to understand what you said. It will be really helpful if you show an example of what you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see a space missing in `"#curve" + i + "path"`.
You can check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-svg----3333-copy-copy-forked-2mglwz?file=/src/components/MainSVG.js

Comment: Heyyyy Simao, 
Thank You so much. If I make another same function outside of the "useEffect". Call that function inside of the useEffect. Then it will work?
Just for organizing the code...

Comment: Yes, but it is not recommended to manipulate "Dom" in React, you can try to optimize it.